# Replacing a word by another with sed - issue

Tags: bash, sed, redhat

On a redhat server,

I have multiple files named `PO*******`
Inside them i have a line like this :

```
NODE PO******* TCPblahblah blah
```

On the other hand i have a csv file containing multiple line like :

```
PO*******,XXXXXXX
```

i want to replace in files `PO*******`
the `NODE PO******* TCPblahblah blah`
by 
`NODE XXXXXX TCPblahblah blah`

See my code for what i did to have this output on line with NODE  : 
TCPblahblXXX

```
for i in $(ls def)
do 
new= $(grep $i list.csv | cut -d ',' -f2)
sed "/NODE/ s/$i/$new/g" def/$i
done
```

Comment: What's your current behaviour? I see at least that you haven't specified `sed`'s `-i`  flag, so the result will be output instead of updating the file. You should check whether the output is correct before fixing that of course. You should also avoid parsing the output of `ls`, `for i in ./def/*` will work better on edge cases (such as spaces in filenames)

Comment: The formatting in this question makes it really awkward to read.

Comment: `*` is a special character in `sed`. For a literal `*` you have to write `\*`. Also don't use `$(ls def)` but `def/*`. You might also want to remove that space after `new= `.

Comment: Are the asterisks literal?

Answer (score 2):

When each `def/*` file only has one `/NODE/` line, you can try a nested `sed`.
Remember that `sed` can use other characters like `,` or `#` when you don't want the `/`.

```
# First look at the generated commands by
sed 's#.*#/NODE/ s,&,#' list.csv
# next try
sed -f <(sed 's#.*#/NODE/ s,&,#' list.csv) def/*
# Make backup before changing
cp -r def def_bak
# Get serious
sed -if <(sed 's#.*#/NODE/ s,&,#' list.csv) def/*
```

When you are not sure about this (overlapping files like PO1 and PO12), you can loop through the files, starting with your csv.

```
while IFS= read -f line; do
   test -f def/"${line%,*}" || continue
   sed -i "s,${line}," def/"${line%,*}"
done < list.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

you have too much blah blah and lacking testable input files, but I think this will do

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} {f=FILENAME; sub(f,a[f]); print > f".mod"}' list.csv def/*
```

this will create ".mod" extensions for the processed files.